# Laravel advanced query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Affiliate has many affiliatesHistory, affiliatesHistory belongs to affiliate, how to make the following query?

Take affiliates, where has affiliatesHistory, if affiliatesHistory records count is equal to 1, then do not take affiliatesHistory, which has status of uninstalled.

```
$affiliates = $user->affiliates()
        ->whereDoesntHave('affiliatesHistory', function ($q) {
        $q->where('affiliates_histories.status', 'Installed earlier')
 ->orWhere('affiliates_histories.status', 'Uninstalled / Installed earlier');
```

The following query works, but I need to not take those affiliates, where affiliatesHistory count is equal to 1 and the status is uninstalled.

Any help will be appriaciated.

Comment: did you try and left join with raw query if you want to follow in that way i can write a answer

Answer (score 0):

So, for what I understand you want to get the affiliates which affiliatesHistory status is Installed earlier. If this is the case then try this:

```php
$user_affiliates =  $user->affiliates(); 
$affiliates = $user_affiliates->whereHas('affiliatesHistory', function($q){
   $q->where('status', 'Installed earlier');
})->get();

dd($affiliates);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case if there are more than one `affiliatesHistory` items then return else if there is only one `affiliatesHistory` then it should not contain Uninstalled status,  I guess you can use conditional count to get desired results as

```
$affiliates = Affiliate::withCount([
    'affiliatesHistory',
    'affiliatesHistory as affiliatesHistoryUninstalled_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'Uninstalled');
    }
    ])->where('user_id', $user->id)
      ->havingRaw('affiliatesHistory_count > 1 OR (affiliatesHistory_count = 1 AND affiliatesHistoryUninstalled_count = 0)')
      ->get();
```